# xpaths - retrieve text inside attribute and split / preg_replace?

Tags: xpath

I have something that looks like this:

```
<strong class="citizen_level" title="<strong>Experience Level</strong><br/>1,137,935 / 1,140,000">252</strong>
```

I managed to extract 252 using :

```
//div[@id='content']/div[@class='citizen_profile_header']/h2/strong
```

But I also want to extract 1,137,935, but they have put that inside a title attribute, which I should be able to extract by using

```
//div[@id='content']/div[@class='citizen_profile_header']/h2/strong/@title
```

Which should output

```
<strong>Experience Level</strong><br/>1,137,935 / 1,140,000
```

Is there any reason the above code wouldnt work ?
And can someone help me here, and get this down to 1137935 ? What would be the best way ?

**Edit:**

```
$string = "<strong>Experience Level</strong><br/>1,137,935 / 1,140,000";

$tmp = preg_replace('/[^0-9\/]/',"",$string);
$tmp = ltrim($tmp, '//');
$tmp = preg_split("/[\/,]+/", $tmp);

$string = reset($string);
```

Maybe not the best way, but it seems to work ? But for some reason

```
//div[@id='content']/div[@class='citizen_profile_header']/h2/strong/@title
```

doesn't seem to work =/

Comment: Your markup is not XML; XML cannot have unescaped markup in attribute values.  XPath requires well-formed XML.

Comment: Obviously its not well formatted XML, but that is the source I have to work from, is there any way to extract the information I need from the attribute ?

Comment: Less obvious, evidently, is that you cannot use tools and standards that require XML on something that's not XML.   You'll have to treat it as text, using character/string processing techniques to achieve your result directly, or repair it to be well-formed XML and then use XPath.

Comment: Okey, sorry for not making it obvious, and the site is a complete html page where we use DOMXpath/DOMDocument to parse it, but as I have tried to explain is the terrible coding by the author of the source document that have put html code inside an attribute, and that is whats causing some headaches. I have been able to retrieve everything else needed from the source document, except that attribute. =/ I'm close to giving up on this.

Comment: So there is no way for Xpath to retrieve the full attribute (with all the html code, and everything), and then later escape it to make it usable ?

Comment: you could use a two-step process, first using an XPath to select the attribute value (which will work as long as markup is properly escaped), and then feeding this value as a document to a second processing step. not pretty, but given how broken the starting point is, maybe the best you can do.

Comment: @taulen: No, you can't use XPath on data that's not XML.  The answer doesn't change with repeated asking.

Comment: @dret: But the whole problem is that the attribute value is not properly escaped, so, no, the first step can't be anything involving XPath.

Comment: @kjhughes Okey, that's a shame but I guess something I need to find a workaround for without using xpath on that part. Thank you for taking the time to explain it.